# Is it possible to toggle two classes in every 3 second using Jquery on page load?

Tags: jquery, css, class, toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#green').toggleClass(green red).setTimeOut(3000);
  $('#red').toggleClass(red green).setTimeOut(3000);
});
```

```css
.wdr{
    width:300px
    height:50px;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.wdg{
    width:150px
    height:100px;
}
.green{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="red" class="wdr red"></div>
<div id ="green" class="wdg green"></div>
```

I'm not too experienced with `jQuery` . In this code I tried to toggle the colors of two `divs` on every 3 sec.but which is not working as expected.Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: For starters open your browser console and look at the errors this code produces. Big clues there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). It will run every x milliseconds giving you the desired result.

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#green').toggleClass('green red');
  }, 3000);

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#red').toggleClass('red green');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.wdr{
  width:300px
    height:50px;
  }
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.wdg{
  width:150px
    height:100px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="red" class="wdr red">
  test
</div>
<div id="green" class="wdg green">
  test
</div>
```

You could also ditch jQuery and use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and it's toggle method for something like this.

```
const green = document.querySelector('#green');
const red = document.querySelector('#red');

setInterval(() => {
  red.classList.toggle('red');
  red.classList.toggle('green');
}, 3000);

setInterval(() => {
  green.classList.toggle('green');
  green.classList.toggle('red');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(function () {
   var flag = false;
    setInterval(function() {
        flag = !flag;
        $("#red").css("background", flag ? "green" : "red");
        $("#green").css("background", flag ? "red" : "green");
    }, 2000);   
});
```

```css
.wdr{
  width:300px
    height:50px;
  }
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
.wdg{
  width:150px
    height:100px;
}
.green{
  background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="red" class="wdr red">
  This is text-1
  </div>
<div id ="green" class="wdg green">
  This is text-2
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, jQuery is only needed for the DOM selectors.  You can also call the method recursively.

```
 var toggleColors = function() {
   $("#red").toggleClass("red green");
   $("#green").toggleClass("green red");
 }

 var maxRunTimes = 10;
 var runTimes = 0;

 function repeat() {
   if (runTimes < maxRunTimes) {
     toggleColors();
     runTimes++;
     setTimeout(repeat, 3000);
   }
 }

 repeat();
```

ps - I added a stop to the recursive call.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtsee2/666c9nq2/)